# how to run function and get data when screen is focus in react navigation v5? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

i have a screen that render a component, favorite songs:

```
class Favorites_Songs extends React.Component {
    
render() {
    const props = {
        tracks: this.props?.tracks, 
        navigation: this.props?.navigation,
    }
    return(
        <>
            <Favorite_Songs_Components {...props}></Favorite_Songs_Components>
        </>
    )
}
```

}

in favorite_songs_component i want to run a function everytime the user go there, so if the user add a new favorite song it can be obtained immediately without closing and open the app again

```
class Favorite_Songs_Components extends React.Component{

state = {
    favorite_songs: "",
}

tracks_length = "";

componentDidMount() {
    this.props?.navigation.addListener("focus", this.get_favorites);
}

get_favorites = async() => {
    let tracks = [...this.props?.tracks];
    let favorites = await Fetch_Favorites();
    this.tracks_length = favorites.length;
    if (favorites === null) {
        this.setState({favorite_songs: "empty"});
    }else {
        let favorites_songs = tracks.filter((tracks) => favorites.includes(tracks.title));
        this.setState({favorite_songs: favorites_songs});
    }
}

render() {
    if (this.state.favorite_songs === "" || this.state.favorite_songs.length != this.tracks_length) {
        return <Text>hola</Text>
    }else {
        const props = {
            route: "favorites", 
            tracks: this.state.favorite_songs,
            navigation: this.props?.navigation,
        }
        return(
            <>
                {
                    (this.state.favorite_songs === "empty") ? 
                    <View style = {this.style.container}>
                        <Text style = {this.style.favorites}>No favorites songs.</Text>
                    </View> : <Tracks {...props}></Tracks>
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

as you can see i already add a listener to it, but everytime i add a new song to favorite and go there it doesnt update inmediately, until i close and re open the app